# Android Webview Not Working After Updating Android System webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Making calls to webpage via javascript interface stopped working after updating Android System webview to v- 92.0.4515.105. This issue is mostly on Samsung devices, running Android 11. Works perfectly fine on other devices.

This is my settings:

```
    // attach the interface 
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    //setup webview settings
        private void setupWebViewClients() {
            this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            this.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                this.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                this.webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                this.webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
            this.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                //App logic
            });
            this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                }
    
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    //App logic
                }
    
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //App logic
                }
    
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                }
    
            });
        }
```

And I am calling functions this way:

```
this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:updateGps('dumny',dummy')";
```

Is there any other settings introduced in Android 11 that I am not aware of? Or it's the bug in Google's Android system webview? Please help me out if there's any work around. Thank you.

Comment: What does `updateGps()` do? Have you examined Logcat to see if you are getting anything from your JavaScript code, such as `console.log()` output? Have you tested with a scrap app that uses a `WebView` but avoids `addJavascriptInterface()`? Have you experimented with replacing `javascript:` and `addJavascriptInterface()` [with web channels](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/23/replacing-addjavascriptinterface-html-message-channels.html)?

Comment: In our app we are sending GPS coordinates every 10 seconds using that method 'updateGps'. It was just an example, we have more javascript methods none of them works anymore, as I said mostly on Samsung devices running Android 11. No I have not tested with scrap app, never did before sorry.. Why do you suggest to experiment by replacing javascript and addJavascripyInterface()?

Comment: Part of our app is written in GWT, so we communicate with GWT using Javascript Interface.

Comment: "Why do you suggest to experiment by replacing javascript and addJavascripyInterface()?" -- because Google has been advising against their use for seven years.

Comment: Wow I have been super late... Could you please suggest any guidance on how to do that? Also, will that effect the old logic? Cause, our app is old and heavily dependent on javascript interfaces

Comment: "Could you please suggest any guidance on how to do that?" -- I linked to [a blog post that I wrote four years ago](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/23/replacing-addjavascriptinterface-html-message-channels.html) in my original comment. "Also, will that effect the old logic?" -- I cannot really answer that. It will affect how you trigger the old logic and get results from it. I would hope that the bulk of your JavaScript (including the GWT-generated parts) would be completely unaffected.

Comment: In the short term, I suggest that you run some tests with a separate tiny ("scrap") app to try to see where exactly your JavaScript communications are breaking down. The only reason to worry about `javascript:` and `addJavascriptInterface()` in the short term is if they have stopped working on those devices, in which case running an experiment with web channels may be worthwhile.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you so much for tips and link that you've given! I am gonna try these out, and see where it leads me :)